# Linking DLL in Visual Studio 2010 C++

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll, hyperlink

I am trying to use the M4RI package for C++. I downloaded the source for M4RI and ran the packaged VS project. It created m4ri.dll (no .lib files). 
Now I want to "add" this dll file to a different VS2010 C++ project so I can use the M4RI library.

I already #include m4ri.h, but still get linking errors. How do I add this reference to the VS project?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution:
I am not familiar with the differences between C and C++, but this seems to be the issue. To get the M4RI library to build, I had to explicitly tell it to compile with C++ (Properties->C/C++->Advanced->Compile As: "Compile as C++")

I'm not sure if this caused my problem, or if it is unrelated.
To be able to *use* the library, I had to modify "m4ri.h" to remove the #ifdef __cplusplus sections. As soon as those precompiler directives were removed, I was able to link to M4RI easily.

I would appreciate if someone could explain *why* this fixed the problem.

Thanks!

Comment: I should also note the other change I made to the original M4RI VS project: I changed it from a DLL to a static library.

Comment: I am reporting these problems to the developer so that they will be fixed for VS in future releases. The problem is the incompatibility between GCC and the MVS compiler. To make the m4ri library compile at all, I have to force it to compile as C++, which means I need to comment out the "extern C" in m4ri.h

Answer (score 0):

Linking errors can come from many things. Are your link errors related to m4ri? With dlls, you usually get a an export lib which should be included in your project.